# Error With Port 8080 already in use

Tags: eclipse, tomcat6, ubuntu-9.10

Can anyone help me to solve the following case?

I am trying to generate my first web site using java and working with Eclipse Galileo running on Ubuntu 9.10. Since I generate my first lines of code I haven't seen the web. All the time when I try to run the program I get the following error:

***Several ports (8080, 8080) required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).***

I have read a lot about the way to change the ports for my tomcat (pass from the 8080 to 80) but it has been impossible. I read some forums where the way to solve this problem is going to the file that contents the server number for tomcat, which is a XML file, but when I open the folder there is not a xml file with the name.

I already explored the port using `sudo lsof -n -P -i` :, start and shut-down tomcat but the mistake is still there.

What can I do?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your apache conf folder, open the httpd file and look for 8080 port. Change 8080 to any port you like. I believe you will find 8080 on two places. Restart your server to see changes.

Comment: Rafe Thanks a lot,I installed again APACHE 2. I saw the directory usr/share/apache2 and inside there are just 4 folders :BUILD,DEFAULT SITE; ERROR; ICONS. Inside those folders I can not see the file that you say. Do you know any command tu find it in linux?

Comment: I installed again APACHE 2. I saw the directory usr/share/apache2 and inside there are just 4 folders :

Comment: I solved the problem I had tow tomcats running at the same time. Thank you.

Comment: i am also facing the same error i have changed the port no , but still getting same error ? can anyone resolve this problem?

Answer (score 34):

Click on servers tab in eclipse and then double click on the server listed there.
Select the port tab in the config page opened.Change the port to any other ports.Restart the server.

Comment: This helped. Note that the IDE is a bit cluttered and the "Port Number" part of the table may be outside the viewport. Image of ports area expanded, on right side of screen. https://i.imgur.com/eZuVILh.png

Answer (score 11):

on Mac, how I usually solve it

1. open terminal and cd to downloaded-apache-files-folder/bin (i.e to the folder where shutdown.sh file is located)
2. enter "sh shutdown.sh" as a terminal command
3. restart Tomcat/Eclipse..tada!

Hope this helps OP or someone else reading

Answer (score 1):

if you are running from inside eclipse with wtp, you should be able to change the port from the "servers" view (window -> show view -> servers)

Comment: I did it, I changed the TOMCAT port 8080 T 80 , but the error is still there. Thanks a lot

Comment: ahh.. how are u starting tomcat?

Comment: From the linux terminal, /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/startup.sh and for stopping /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/shutdown.sh.

Comment: I solved the problem I had tow tomcats running at the same time. Thank you.

Comment: oh well the eclipse settings will only work if you are starting from wtp... is there a reason that you are not?

Comment: If the server is set to 'User Workspace metadata' vs 'Use Tomcat Installation' would the file be updated correctly? I may be overthinking this but I figured I would ask anyway.

Comment: I would guess that the workspace metadata is actually used via commandline when starting tomcat where possible, and will update the tomcat conf files only if necessary. I am actually using the sysdeo tomcat plugin at this point to avoid all the overhead with WTP. http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html

Answer (score 1):

It has been long time, but I faced the same Issue, and solved it as follow:
1. tried shutting down the application server using the shutdown.bat/.bash which might be in your application Server / bin/shutdown..

2. My Issue, was that more than 1 instance of java was running, I was changing ports, and not looking back, so it kept running  other java processes, with that specific port.
   for windows users, : ALT+Shift+Esc, and end java processes that you are not using and now you should be able to re-use your port 8080

Answer (score 1):

You've another instance of Tomcat already running. You can confirm this by going to http://localhost:8080 in your webbrowser and check if you get the Tomcat default home page or a Tomcat-specific 404 error page. Both are equally valid evidence that Tomcat runs fine; if it didn't, then you would have gotten a browser specific HTTP connection timeout error message.

You need to shutdown it. Go to /bin subfolder of the Tomcat installation folder and execute the shutdown.bat (Windows) or shutdown.sh (Unix) script.

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5065874/6646796) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue is:

**Step 1:** Stop Tomcat(By service or by .bat/.sh what ever the case may be ).

**Step 2:** Delete the already configured Apache Tomcat on eclipse.

**Step 3:** Now reconfigure the apache on the eclipse and start the server using UI as provided by eclipse.

I have the same issue and it has worked.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me >
In Eclipse NEON double clicked on Server tab which redirects server overview window

Here you can change port number based on your requirement for Tomcat Admin and HTTP port.

And restarted the server.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem , here's the solution.

**Step 1 :** Double click on the server listed in Eclipse. Here It will display Server Configuration.

**Step 2 :** Just change the port Number like from 8080 to 8085.

**Step 3 :** Save the changes.

**Step 4 :** re-start your server.

The server will start .Hope it'll help you.