# Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat Server at localhost are already in use

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm getting the following error when I try to run a simple JSP program on Tomcat in Eclipse.

> Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: I had a similar issue which turned out to be the windows firewall.

Comment: Probably some undead process is keeping your tomcat alive. kill the process either by finding its ID and terminating it or by restarting your machine.

Comment: you can use these command to stop the tomcat services already running from the command console. `netstat -ano | findStr 8080` to find the running services and then find the process id and copy the pid and run the command again as `taskkill /F /PID pid_number`

Answer (score 502, accepted):

You've another instance of Tomcat already running. You can confirm this by going to `http://localhost:8080` in your webbrowser and check if you get the Tomcat default home page or a Tomcat-specific 404 error page. Both are equally valid evidence that Tomcat runs fine; if it didn't, then you would have gotten a browser specific HTTP connection timeout error message.

You need to shutdown it. Go to `/bin` subfolder of the Tomcat installation folder and execute the `shutdown.bat` (Windows) or `shutdown.sh` (Unix) script. If in vain, close Eclipse and then open the task manager and kill all `java` and/or `javaw` processes.

Or if you actually installed it as a Windows service for some reason (this is namely intented for production and is unhelpful when you're just developing), open the services manager (*Start > Run > services.msc*) and stop the Tomcat service. If necessary, uninstall the Windows service altogether. For development, just the ZIP file is sufficient.

Or if your *actual* intent is to run two instances of Tomcat simultaneously, then you have to configure the second instance to listen on different ports. Consult the Tomcat documentation for more detail.

Comment: perfect, this has been plaguing me forever. I executed it as `sh shutdown.sh` in terminal within the /bin directory.

Comment: Hello BalusC, I like you ! There is no `shutdown.bat` in my bin folder. Tomcat was installed as a service and not as a zip. Stopping tomcat service in services fixed the problem. Thanks. Chenqui.

Comment: @Borat: You're welcome. Keep in mind that you'd really better uninstall the service and get the zip instead.

Comment: Or other software is using those ports (ex: Skype)

Comment: @BalusC: I'm a complete newb here, so this might not make sense, but here's what's in my head when you say that: what *if I want to use that instance of tomcat you're telling me to shut down*.  (I.e, how do I configure to use that tomcat instance? How do I publish to it?)

Comment: @notfed: let it listen on a different port. See also last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: use sudo service tomcat7 shutdown to stop the service in linux system and then open the eclipse then start the tomcat7. It will work.

Comment: "kill all java and/or javaw processes" worked for me, thanks.

Comment: Opening the `system monitor` or `task manager` and killing a java process which is using `about 400 MB` or more `RAM` will also solve the problem. It is unknowingly reserving the process.

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks. for the answer! "You've another instance of Tomcat already running."  By "instance", do you mean process? So does eclipse run tomcat in a different process from the tomcat process run from command line?

Comment: Hi,

I'm using spring boot and i'm getting the same issue for any ports. 
for me there are no java / javaw processes running.
Please help.

Comment: @BalusC You saved me. I uninstalled the Tomcat and just used .zip file. Voila! Now I ran the first JSP program! Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 58):

```
kill $(ps -aef | grep java | grep apache | awk '{print $2}')
```

- no need to restart Eclipse
- if you get the above error, just enter this line in terminal
- again start the tomcat in Eclipse.
- works only in Linux based system ( Ubuntu ..etc )

Comment: This is better `kill $(ps -aef | grep java | grep apache | awk '{print $2}')`

Comment: This does not work for me (Mint 17.1). It just gives me the help for the `kill` command.

Comment: This worked for me. However I wanted to know if I have 2 instances running and I have to force stop one using this method, how do I figure out which to shut. Thanks

Answer (score 32):

If you are running on windows try this in the command line prompt:

```
netstat -ano
```

This will show all ports in use and the process id PID # of the process that is using that port.
Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and open Task Manager to see which process is that.

You can then choose either to close/stop it or configure your server to use another port.
To check if the new choosen port (let's say 8010) is available do this:

```
netstat -ano | grep 8010
```

If it does not return any lines then you are fine.

To change the port go to the Server view, open **server.xml** and change the port there.
Mine has this entry:

```
Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"
```

Comment: Please see my new answer in which I include a PowerShell script to automate this without requiring you to open Task Manager.

Comment: `findstr` for those without grep.

Answer (score 27):

If you are on mac environment, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18706913/926460) is what I did.

Find the process id running on this port from terminal, eg, 8080:

```
lsof -i :8080
```

and kill it:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Example:

You may see following result:

```
MacSys:bin krunal.$ lsof -i :8080

COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE  SIZE/OFF   NODE  NAME
java     21347   krunal  52u  IPv6      XXX      0t0      TCP  *:http-xxx (LISTEN)
```

and kill it: (`kill -9 21347`)

Answer (score 27):

Steps to free port which is already used to run tomcat server in Eclipse

For example , suppose 8080 port is used , we need to make free 8080 to run tomcat

Step 1:

C:\Users\username>netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:8080

TCP    0.0.0.0:3000      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3116

Now , we can see that LISTENING port is 3116 for 8080 ,

We need to kill 3116 now

Step 2:-

C:\Users\username>taskkill /F /PID 3116

Step 3:
Go to Eclipse and start Server , it will run

Comment: Bless you dear sir. Now I believe in God.

Comment: Just waouh ! +1 year on your life :)

Answer (score 16):

If you use Eclipse then double click on servers and double click on tomcat server then one file will open. In that file change HTTP port to some other port number and save(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) then again start the server.

Comment: This worked for me while the other solutions did not. I'm using Mint 17.1. I had to install tomcat both thru Eclipse and thru apt-get because I could not find the folder where apt-get installed it. So that's presumably why I have two. Still I could not close the first one with the kill commands.

Answer (score 12):

If Eclipse says

> Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost are already in use

This error comes because tomcat may be running in background so first stop that server..follow the below details.

Solution is:

1. Open the "console" view (window->show view->Console)
2. Then stop the tomcat server.
3. Then open the "server" view and start the server it will work.

Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. I only tried: sudo service tomcat stop

Answer (score 11):

I have no another instance of Tomcat running ad no other process using "Tomcat port" (in my case, the 8088 port).
Eclipse send the same message on starting Tomcat:

*....The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).*

I solve the problem in this way:

- go to bin of tomcat by prompt
- launch startup.bat
- launch shutdown.bat
- start tomcat by Eclipse

Comment: My problem was that 8005 and 8009 ports were busy, however 8080 port was free and no tomcat installation was running at that time. Your solution helped me to fix this issue, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! If you can't find the port being used by any other process, this is the solution you should opt for.

Answer (score 7):

What I did after reading all the suggested answer and as I know my port was already in use. I double clicked on Tomcat under the Servers tab in eclipse and it opened overview information and then find port information. Just changed conflicting port as mine was 8009 port (error mentioned during starting the server). I have changed it to 8008 and it works fine. Give a try if the changed port would not be in use server will start.

Answer (score 7):

**Step 1:** **netstat -a -o -n** and it will bring up a network list,search for the local address like 127.0.0.1:8080 and note the PID (eq 3624)

```
C:\>netstat -a -o -n
```

**Step2 :** **taskkill /F /PID 3624** . Run this command to kill that process.

```
C:\>taskkill /F /PID 3624
```

link to [post](http://sandeepbhardwaj.github.io/2011/11/28/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required.html)

Comment: Please see my new answer in which I include a PowerShell script to automate these two lines.

Answer (score 6):

***On Windows use command*** for stopping the already running tomcat instance and try running it again in eclipse, it may work.

```
net stop tomcat7
```

Or you can ***change the port in server's XML*** if you just want to run on some other ports.

Answer (score 4):

Easy way to solve your problem:

The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. In order to kill that port, do the following:

1) Download **TCPView(only 285kb)** from following link.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx

2) Extract folder and start **TCPView** application.

3) Right click on **java.exe**(because 8009,8005 ports are commonly used by java process) and select **End Process** option.

this would stop another process easily..

**NOTE**: Running **TOMCATPATH/bin/shutdown.bat** may not shutdown Tomcat when it contains some demon or unmanaged 
      threads. In such cases **TCPView** works fine without any issues.

Answer (score 3):

I checked all the answers but `informing only to kill PID`.

In case if **you have terminal access shared by all** it will not help or **maybe you do not have permission to kill PID**.

In this case what you can do is:

`Double click on server`

`Go to Overview and change ports in Ports` like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are in Java EE prospective in Eclipse and trying to start the Tomcat Server in Eclipse in debug mode, then you will get such errors. You must switch to debug prospective in Eclipse. I have solved my problem like this.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes if the ports are not freed even after attempting shutdown.bat what @BalusC suggested,you can kill the javaw process. Do following steps :

1. Click on Start Menu and open "Windows powershell"
2. Right click before opening and select "Run as administrator"
3. Enter command ps. You may see a image as follows :
   [image: Powershell showing current proesses running]
4. See the process number of process "javaw".The process number is the rightmost number in the columns, I have highlighted in the image process number of javaw for example.
5. Enter command kill . javaw is killed and now you must be able to run the program.

Comment: Please see my new answer in which I include a PowerShell script to automate this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more option to try if none of the efforts above helped. **You might be using Eclipse from a Shared Drive (for eg, H:)**. If so, move/copy it the entire Eclipse directory to C: and try again.

My Eclipse could not open ports for Tomcat server (with the above error), nor even connect to internet. I also tried another Tomcat plugin (Sysdeo) which failed to open the ports too.

These are the options I tried:

**Check and Kill Other Tomcat Instances**

- In command prompt, `netstat -ano` and check if any other processes are using the conflicted ports.
- Find the PID and kill it
- Try starting the server again.

**Change Tomcat Ports in Eclipse**

- In Eclipse Server tab, double click the Tomcat instance. This will open the configuration tab.
- Under Ports, change the port numbers. (for eg, 18080).

**Kill java.exe and javaw**

- In Task Manager, find and kill java.exe and javaw (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25334782/4212710 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/26136890/4212710)
- Try starting the server again.

See my other answer for Eclipse not connecting to Internet (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37246087/4212710).

Answer (score 2):

For windows users:

Go to Task Manager directly with CTRL+SHIFT+ESC key combination.

Kill the "java.exe" processes by right clicking and selecting "End Task".

Answer (score 1):

The simpler fix that works for me is deleting my current deployed webapps from tomcat through the "Server" tab. Once I remove them the problem goes away. Simply re-deploy your project by going on Run As > Run on Server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem often arises when Apache Tomcat fails to terminate, properly, even though a shutdown instruction was sent. In my case, using Tomcat 8, this happens with annoying regularity. Luckily, you can use Windows PowerShell and the `netstat` command to create a simple script to kill the process.

The following PowerShell script will parse the output from `netstat` to find any process that is listening on `127.0.0.1:8005`, extract its PID and then kill that process:

```
netstat -a -o -n `
 | select -skip 4 `
 | % {$a = $_ -split ' {3,}'; New-Object 'PSObject' -Property @{Original=$_;Fields=$a}} `
 | ? {$_.Fields[1] -match '127\.0\.0\.1\:8005$'} `
 | % {Write-Host "Killing PID" $_.Fields[4] "..."; taskkill /F /PID $_.Fields[4] }
```

If your `server.xml` configures Tomcat to use a different port or IP, edit the regular expression on the script's fourth line accordingly.

Finally, I should point out that the situation is better on Linux because you can instruct Tomcat to save its PID to a file at startup-time and use a switch to force the shutdown, later - the shutdown script for 'nix systems already features the ability to kill the process and the sleuth-work with `netstat` is not required.

Answer (score 1):

If the above issue occurs in Windows 7 or 10 based OS, the problem occurs because Tomcat is running as Windows Service. To stop Tomcat running as Windows Services, Open Windows Control Panel. Find the service "Apache Tomcat" and Stop it.
The Another way is to kill the process running on port 8080 using cmd.

Open cmd running it as administrator.

1. C:\users\username>netstat -o -n -a|findstr 0.0:8080
2. TCP   0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2160.
3. The above 2160 is process id of process running on port 8080 and kill that process using the following command
   C:\users\username>taskkill /F /PID 2160
4. Go to IDE and start Server, it will run

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you are not stopping your tomcat service properly. To do that, **Open your task manager** there you can see a `javaw.exe` service. First stop that service. Now restart your tomcat it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to close your eclipse IDE.Your Tomcat is probably running already. That's why you have got an error.

open tomcat directory >> bin >> from command terminal (in my case is tomcat9)

Enter command

./shutdown.sh

it will close your running tomcat

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was giving me the error: **Port 8005 required by Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost is already in use**

I changed 8005 port in apache-tomcat-8.0.39\conf\server.xml but changes were not getting reflected. Then I did these changes from eclipse. by double clicking server and modifying the port from 8005 to 8006 and it works. 
[image]

Before putting 8006 I checked in windows shell if this port is available or not. By executing following command:

```
netstat -a -o -n | findstr 8006
```

Answer (score 1):

I face the same problem and after searching the answer as shown below:
1. open Monitor Tomcat as shown below:
[image]

2. Simply press stop as shown in below picure:

[image]

Finally it works with me after many trials and suggested solutions.

Best Regards,
Kerelos Mikhail

Answer (score 1):

**Macbook solution:**

***Step 1:** stop the server running Java :*

Open Activity Monitor by going to Applications > Utilities > Activity Monitor. Or simple press CMD + Spacebar and start typing Activity Monitor.
Look for process running Java and kill it by giving the following command in Terminal

```
kill -STOP <PID>
```

where PID is the process ID of the Java process as displayed in the Activity Monitor. Do it a couple of times and close and reopen Activity Monitor to check Java isn't running.

***Step 2**: change the port :*

right-click on the server in Eclipse and click 'Open'. Change port number from 8080 to 8081 or something greater in value.

This should hopefully start your server.

Answer (score 1):

In windows open Task Manager (Ctrl+Alt+Delete) and go to Services tab then right click tomcat and select stop then start in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and followed the below steps to resolve it.

You can check whether port 8080 is really used now by opening this link.
http://localhost:8080/

If it is showing the `Apache Tomcat`page follow the below steps to resolve the issue.

1. Open `Services` (This can be done by searching on the search bar on your PC)
2. Find `Apache Tomcat` among the services.

[image: Apache Tomcat]

3. Check the status of `Apache Tomcat`. It should currently at the `Running` state.
4. Right-click on it and click on `stop` to stop the `server`.

[image: Apache Tomcat]

5. Now close the `Services` app and re-run your `program` on the `Apache Tomcat server`.

Now your program will work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following blog "how to kill tomcat without have to restart your computer"

http://stanicblog.blogspot.fr/2012/01/how-to-kill-apache-tomcat-without.html

Hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: The link above is dead. This one points to the good blog article : http://stanicblog.blogspot.fr/2012/01/how-to-kill-apache-tomcat-without.html

Comment: Please do not add links to read without mentioning important part.
Because People are here get answers.

Answer (score 0):

On Eclipse make a raw delete of Tomcat configuration folder under project "Servers".
I tried it as last hope and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In case of windows, I experienced a new stuff...
stopping tomcat from /bin folder will immediately not releasing the port 8080. It takes around 5-10 mins to release the port. After 10 mins again if i try to run my project
Run-> Run on server .. it allows to run.

I'm unsure whether my understanding is correct!

Answer (score 0):

> Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat vX.X Server at localhost are already in use

To check whether another instance of Tomcat already running or some other process is using the ports you can use:

> `netstat -b -a` in command prompt for windows. This lists the ports in use and gives you the executable that's using each one. You need to be in the admin group to do this.

You might get something like this:

> `TCP   192.168.0.1:8009      192.168.0.1:0  LISTENING 196 [Tomcat7.exe]`
>
> `TCP   192.168.0.1:8080      192.168.0.1:0  LISTENING 196 [Tomcat7.exe]`
>
> `TCP   192.168.0.1:8005      192.168.0.1:0  LISTENING 196 [Tomcat7.exe]`

Open task manager <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, and kill `Tomcat7.exe` or any other process using these ports.

Comment: Please see my new answer in which I include a PowerShell script to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when others in the project are also using the same port numbers as you are using!
double click tomcat server, change port numbers to anything 8585 or whatever. The code will now begin to run!

Answer (score 0):

How to kill a windows service using PID -

1. open command prompt and type `netstat -ano`
2. find the PID of the ports which are in used, in this case, it will be 8080, 8005,8009. Let's say PID of these ports are 5760.
3. Now Type `taskkill /f /pid 5760`
4. it will close the PID and ports will be available for use. Now you can start tomcat as normal by Windows services or by eclipse itself.

Thanks

[kill a Windows service that's stuck on stopping or starting](http://www.examiner.com/list/how-to-kill-a-windows-service-that-s-stuck-on-stopping-or-starting)

Answer (score 0):

Your Tomcat is probably running already. That's why you have got an error. I've had the same problem before. I solved it very simply:

1. Restart your computer
2. Open Eclipse
3. Run your Tomcat

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

In windows OS do right click on task bar-->start task manager-->process then check **java.exe or javaw** is running if it is running,then click on it and do end process then restart your tom cat server.

2. some times skype will occupy port 80 in that case change the skype settings and put 81 for skype or change tomcat configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest solution**

Single line command for killing multiple ports:

```
kill $(lsof -t -i:8005,8080,8009)
```

8005, 8080 and 8009 are the ports to be freed.

Alternatively, you can try `sudo kill sudo lsof -t -i:8005` in linux.

Comment: sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:3000`

Answer (score 0):

All of above do not work for me.

What I found was click the Details button.
[image]

Then following the [Multiple contexts with the same path error running web service in Eclipse using Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239613/multiple-contexts-with-the-same-path-error-running-web-service-in-eclipse-using)

Removed the duplicated line then I got an another error.

```
The server cannot be started because one or more of the ports are invalid. Open the server editor and correct the invalid ports.
```

Following [Can't start tomcatv9.0 in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471438/cant-start-tomcatv9-0-in-eclipse)

Then it works.