# Failed to start component - ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I have gone through similar posts around. I have tried most of those solutions but was not able to get rid of the error I am getting. Expecting some help on this.

This error came after I added maven dependancies to deployment assembly. I am using STS with Pivotal tc Server Development Edition v3.1.  I already checked the version of tc server and java home. Both use java 8.

I cannot understand what the problem is.

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@95e0743]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4850)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4982)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6a44e649]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:137)
    ... 17 more

Dec 03, 2016 10:34:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor E:\Programs\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.2.0.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\Catalina\localhost\myProject.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1805)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The following is my pom.xml. Error came when I tried to add spring-webmvc dependancy to pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.infiniteskills.mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j13</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please help me resolve this. I am stuck with this.

Comment: You may have a corrupted JAR file somewhere http://stackoverflow.com/a/38856033/2308683

Comment: I have added the dependancies using maven. and the error comes only when i try to use spring-webmvc 4.3.4 RELEASE

Comment: Right. And Maven downloads JAR files and one of those could easily be corrupted

Comment: Another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310474/hibernate-commons-annotations-4-0-1-final-jar-invalid-loc-header-bad-signature and one more...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14495040/tomcat-server-fails-to-start-the-server-and-application-in-sts

Comment: Thankyou. The problem got solved.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I have solved similar kind of problem by deleting all files present in local maven repository and downloading them again.

linux or mac users can follow below steps for deleting all files.

1. navigate to .m2 file
2. execute remove command (rm -rf repository/).

Answer (score 4):

Nagivate to your C:\Users\user.m2\repository\projects\project1

Pick the corresponding project and delete it from your .m2. Then do mvn clean install in the terminal it will recreate those jar files for you  Reinstall the ear or war file in server and it should deploy just fine now.