# Transitive dependency causing build failure

Tags: java, maven, transitive-dependency

I am creating building a jar which will also include its dependencies. I am using maven shade plugin for this. But getting `Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header` error while building. I tried excluding the transitive dependency as shown below still getting error.

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.tlt.idk</groupId>
<artifactId>saba-user-import</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>CSVSabaUserImport</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons.lang3</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
         <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>ImportCsv</mainClass>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Problem shading JAR C:\Users\Admin.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar entry META-INF/LICENSE.txt: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.DefaultShader.shadeJars(DefaultShader.java:197)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.DefaultShader.shade(DefaultShader.java:106)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:442)
>       ... 21 more
>   Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Would you please be able to post your full `pom.xml` to see if there's anything else that may be related to this problem? Also, have you tried `mvn dependency:tree` to see if any other dependency pulls in `apache-commons`? Just want to eliminate some of the more straightforward possibilities.

Comment: Post also full stack trace including all information ..with Maven Shade 3.1.1 there should be supplemental information about the wrong jar file...Furthermore I recommend to fail your build if checksums are wrong this needs to be activated via settings.xml file (checksum policy)..

Comment: @JustinAlbano posted full pom.. already tried mvn dependecy:tree. opencvs is having it as trasitive depedency.

Comment: @khmarbaise commons.lang3 is causing the isse

Comment: try with deleting the commons-lang3 jar from local maven repo and let it download again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to start component - ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945116/failed-to-start-component-zipexception-invalid-loc-header-bad-signature)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there was an error downloading the dependency. This happend quite often when eclipse downloaded the dependencies for me.

Delete the corrupted artifact from your maven cache (located in `C:\Users\<username>\.m2\respository`).