# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;failed to start component

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat8, hibernate-jpa

After deploying/replacing the class files in Tomcat 8 I got the following error. I haven't been able to find (or properly implement) a solution to the problem at hand yet. Any help would be appreciated!

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
service Catalina
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting
Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.50
SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1]
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start
component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:943)
atorg.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
atorg.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component \[StandardServer\[8005\]\]A child container failed during start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753473/org-apache-catalina-lifecycleexception-failed-to-start-component-standardserve)

Comment: this is not solving my query, can you please provide some more insight