# while setup my intellij the following errors occurred

Tags: java

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [WebappLoader[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:1007) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1445) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1434) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:1001) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:474) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:380) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:250) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopSilently(TomcatWebServer.java:238) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:124) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.itgig.api.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [WebappLoader[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:267) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1445) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1434) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:1001) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field static final java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @7ff2a664
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearCache(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesObjectStreamClassCaches(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2194) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferences(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1567) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.stop(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1497) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stopInternal(WebappLoader.java:442) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 42 common frames omitted

2023-02-23 09:15:26.405 ERROR 34040 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during stop

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during stop
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:1007) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:474) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:380) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:250) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopSilently(TomcatWebServer.java:238) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:124) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.itgig.api.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during stop
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:1015) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1445) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1434) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:1001) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

I can't resolve how to setup intellij

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10373077/12715723 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/28753473/12715723

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not many details provided, but it looks like you're using a newer Java version that isn't supported by the version of Spring Boot you're using.