# Getting error when running maven project second time in eclipse ide

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to maven. When i run the project for the first time i get this output in console

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HelloWorld Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ HelloWorld >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ HelloWorld ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ HelloWorld <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at /home/yahooda/Documents/workspace-sts-3.4.0.RELEASE/HelloWorld/target/tomcat
Oct 16, 2013 10:46:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
INFO: Starting tomcat server
Oct 16, 2013 10:46:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
Oct 16, 2013 10:46:38 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Oct 16, 2013 10:46:38 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

When i run the same project again i am getting this error in console

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HelloWorld Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ HelloWorld >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ HelloWorld ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ HelloWorld <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ HelloWorld ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at /home/yahooda/Documents/workspace-sts-3.4.0.RELEASE/HelloWorld/target/tomcat
Oct 16, 2013 10:47:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded start
INFO: Starting tomcat server
Oct 16, 2013 10:47:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
Oct 16, 2013 10:47:39 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:549)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:830)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:538)
    ... 26 more

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.490s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 16 10:47:39 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/84M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) on project HelloWorld: Could not start Tomcat: Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8080 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

If i close my eclipse and start again, then project works fine for the first time.

Answer : I get answers for this is stop tomcat from command line or restart the elipse or change the port no.

I just installed m2e plugin in eclipse, so i cannot stop through command line. I dont want to restart my eclipse everytime and change my port no. Is there any other way to do this. Can't we stop or start tomcat from eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in us
```

Tomcat is already in starting mode.

To start again you need to stop it first and then start again.Or you can restart the TOMCAT.
It will take care about stopping and starting server.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to re-run the application without killing the first tomcat server

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use <null>:8080
```

Kill that instance first. then re-run.

Comment: How to kill first instance ? In eclipse servers it is already stopped position.

Comment: You can do it from the command line with `mvn tomcat:stop`
..or restarting eclipse will do the job :p

Comment: Can't we do without restarting eclipse and from the command line ?

Answer (score 0):

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use

you are encountering this problem because you are not closing an instance of tomcat which is already running and you are trying to run it again

so you can do two things either close first instance and re-run and if problem persists change the port by following method.

> open server.xml search for 8080 and change it to 8081

check [this answer for closing tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre)

Comment: How to close first instance ?

Comment: go to server tab in your eclipse and then click on red button to stop server

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn tomcat:stop
```

Use this before tomcat:start.

See your console view. It has a red button to stop your application.

See doc [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/context-goals.html)