# Server gives port number error on second time when i run it

Tags: java, apache, server, port-number

I'm using tomcat v7.0 in STS,initially it was showing (8080 port number is already in use)error, i tried and fixed that problem by killing the current application using that port number and run the server. Not only that i also changed port number and ran application.It worked well, Problem is first time it works ..later same error occurs. Please can anyone help me out here.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have another instance running. Close that one first. Duplicate question, I saw it pass by last week, marked as a duplicate already.

- [Getting error when running maven project second time in eclipse ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395771/getting-error-when-running-maven-project-second-time-in-eclipse-ide)