# How to install tomcat in linux(centos 6.4)?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, installation, tomcat7

I downloaded Tomcat server from this link : http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi.

How to install this Tomcat 7. Try to give some good commands for this purpose.
**I'm new to LINUX**(i don't know any commands for how to install a packages in linux).

Please suggest.

Comment: Afaik.. there is a compressed package available for linux on apache downloads, copy it into the desired folder and extract it... done!

Comment: The download page should have installation instructions.

Comment: there is no installation instructions.@devnull

Comment: There are many tutorials available, see e. g. [this one](http://www.lejnieks.com/2008/installing-tomcat-on-centos/).  Please describe what you tried so far and what did not work.

Comment: how to compress my downloaded file @codeMan

Comment: @codeMan there is no instruction for linux

Comment: @ram why would you want to compress your downloaded folder?

Comment: thaks for response but am new to linux, how to make folder in terminal @codeMan

Comment: mkdir new_directory_name

Comment: in ur previous comment **download folder and extract**.thats y i said

Comment: @codeMan pls tell me step by step process for installation tomcat7.I'll follow you pls pls pls pls pls tel me step by step procedure

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41017/discussion-between-ram-and-codeman)

Comment: please come to chat...

Comment: @hello codeMan pls pls pls pls come to chat.pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to your downloaded folder

```
ex : cd /home/<user>/Downloads
```

Now to extract the file use the following command :

```
tar -xvzf apache-tomcat-7.0.47.tar.gz
```

Now u have extracted that to a folder. To check the folder name

```
ls | grep apache
```

Now to run start the server :

now go to that folder

```
cd /apache-tomcat-7.0.47/bin/
sh startup.sh
```

To check if the server is running, type this in your browser

```
localhost:8080
```

If you see an sample page, you are done installing.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to it move the tomcat directory to appropriate place I put it in **/opt** .
From your download folder use the following command.*(this step is recommended but not necessary to run tomcat)*

```
sudo mv apache-tomcat-7.0.47 /opt/apache-tomcat7
```

and if you want to use the tomcat manager GUI set up a user with manager-gui role by editing **/opt/apache-tomcat7/conf/tomcat-users.xml** and make the following changes. *(Open the file in any editor to make these changes.)*

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: -->
<!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
</tomcat-users>

Comment: this is there in tomcat-users.xml

Comment: add <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/> between opeaning and closing <tomcat-users> and use that credentials to access Tomcat Manager

Comment: my problem-- Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

Comment: how to resolve this..

Comment: [Check this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre)