# Tomcat can be started using startup.bat but not from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have installed apache tomcat 7.0.47. I have used netbeans for a while, now i want to try eclipse. I've installed eclipse kepler. I have created my first struts application using it.

I have deployed few applications from netbeans which worked well. Now i cannot start up the tomcat server from eclipse. I'm getting message as

> Several ports (8005, 8181, 8009) required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

I have checked that no javaws.exe running in process explorer. Also checked no processes using the port 8181 using netstat.

When i start the tomcat from bin using startup.bat it starts normally and i have checked in browser. It is showing the default page on localhost:8181 and listed in netstat.

Any way to start my first struts application in eclipse. Tried almost every thing but no improvement.

Comment: Have you configured the Tomcat connector in Eclipse correctly? Does Tomcat 7 shows up in the properties.?

Comment: yes, in new server runtime environment i have chosen tomcat 7.

Comment: prithvi have you stopped the tomcat yousing shutdown.bat? then try starting it from eclipse http://stackoverflow.com/a/5065874/2334391

Comment: Tried it. But same message pops up.

Comment: Yes i have tried it. Restarted system, ensured no processes running in 8181, tried in eclipse. Still not working.

Comment: Can you paste the configurations you've set for Tomcat in eclipse.?