# tomcat v8.0 doesn't start at ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, server, ubuntu-14.04

i'm new here, sorry if i asked bad question
it's about Tomcat, i have ubuntu 14.04 ans eclipse
i installed Tomcat v8.0 and when i start it, it doesn't worked and show me this error message :

"Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)."

i need solution and thank you very much

Comment: On which port you are trying to run you Tomcat server?

Comment: and what is already running on that port? this has nothing to do with your os. If the port is taken, tomcat can't use it.

Comment: One possible reason is that an instance of Tomcat is already running: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre

Comment: try `lsof -i` in terminal to check if there is something already running in thoses ports. (maybe a background tomcat ?)

Answer (score 0):

Either you stop the service(s) which are running on those ports (you can find out which those are with "lsof -i" like suggested by flafoux or have a look at http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/ for alternatives) or you change the port of your Tomcat. For that you need to modify the ports in the file "{tomcat-directory}/conf/server.xml" (see the documentation [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/server.html) and [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html) if you need more details).