# starting tomcat server at localhost

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat8

When I run my application on the server in Eclipse, I have the message: "Port 8080 required by Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server, you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)". Other projects are closed. Can anybody help me with the problem? I`m beginner in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop the service before trying to start it again. This problem appears sometimes and you have to open the tomcat monitor and stop the service manually. Try it and run the process again from eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

you can go to conf directory and locate server.xml file and go to line started by connector context and change the port from 8080 to any port you like and start tomcat server.
you can follow this guide : https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/

Answer (score 0):

Referring this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5065874/7004388).

> - Go to `/bin` subfolder of the Tomcat installation folder and execute the `shutdown.bat` (Windows) or `shutdown.sh` (Unix) script.
> - If in vain, close Eclipse and then open the task manager and kill all java and/or javaw processes.