# What does tomcat require ports 8005 and 8009 for?

Tags: tomcat

For which operations does tomcat need ports 8005 and 8009 ?? What will happen if  or my tomcat is behind a proxy on which those ones are closed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat Server at localhost are already in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre)

Comment: What on earth does [tag:jira] have to do with it?