# Port 8005 is used By Windows 10 System Process

Tags: windows, tomcat

Since today, the port 8005 is used for a Windows System Process. When i try to acces to the url http:localhost:8005 ,i can see a Blank Web Page, with no code and no info from any Web Server (No welcome web page or similar).

With the netstat command i can see that the process that uses this port is System process. Any idea why windows is using suddenly this port?

EDIT: Not duplicate question. I don't have another Tomcat installation, the problem comes from a windows process, not for another tomcat instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat Server at localhost are already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problems comes from a Windows Service:

https://www.niallbrady.com/2017/02/15/how-can-i-use-express-updates-when-patching-windows-10-with-quality-updates-in-system-center-configuration-manager-current-branch/

Not from another Tomcat instance.

Answer (score 21):

Check if port 8005 is really in use by Windows :

Install and run [Sysinternals TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) and
Check if the line with "Local Port" 8005 has as "Process" System

Or check the file c:\Windows\CCM\Logs\DeltaDownload.log for port 8005

If the port is in use by system, go to Computer Management and stop the service "SMS Agent Host" or open a command prompt as administrator and type:
    sc stop CcmExec

Comment: 1) open Command Prompt(right click ->run as administrator) 2)type "netstat -aon| find /i "listening" |find "8005", you will see your pid at the end of the line. Mine is "4" which is system. 3)go to Computer Managerment and stop the service "SMS Agent Host"

Answer (score 2):

I too was facing the same with windows 10 and ran the command **netstat -a -b** which showed **CmRcService.exe** is using the port 8005 on the machine.

The most weird part is sometimes if i hit localhost:8005 in the browser url its asking for username and password to access the page and in the developers tools I cannot see any application name or data whatsoever

Comment: I just noticed this today on my pc. It's a bit concerning that there's some unknown webserver asking for login credentials. Did you ever find out what this is?

Answer (score 2):

As already said in other answers, if the port is used by "System" the culprit should be the [SMS Agent Host](https://serverfault.com/q/22650/284524).  Other answers simply say to stop it but I have a corporate PC and I assume that the service is running because a sysadmin wants it.

If, like me, you want to run Tomcat on your workstation, the solution is to modify `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml`: search for a line that says

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

and put a free port number in it.