# Bonita BPM: Tomcat port is already in use

Tags: tomcat, port, bonita

I tried running a Bonita instance on my localhost using Tomcat, but I got an error message saying that the Tomcat port is already in use.

[image: Tomcat cannot be launched]

I checked in the terminal and found that the port that it's trying to connect to (and said that it's in use) is in use by itself. In other words, the task that is using that said port is the Tomcat instance that I just tried to start.

I have tried restarting Bonita, restarting my laptop, killed the instance that is using the port, to no use. This problem has occurred twice, and before this, I "solved" the issue by uninstalling Bonita + Tomcat and reinstalling it again. I don't want to have to reinstall every time I come across this issue, and I prefer not to change the port number Tomcat uses.

Is there any other way to solve it? Also, if anyone may suggest me what could cause this issue, I would very much appreciate that.

Thank you.

EDIT 1: I'm running Bonita BPM 7.3.2, Tomcat v7, on Windows 10 64-bit

EDIT 2: I have also tried to restart the web server, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It seems it's time to update your [windows settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147510/port-8005-is-used-by-windows-10-system-process)

Comment: @m4gic I checked the linked question but I think my case might be different from that one. The port is used by 2 of the same pid, killing one results in automatically killing both processes off.  Although, I might be wrong since I'm not very well-versed in this area, would it be possible, if windows services is using the port, for it to have the same PID as the tomcat instance?

Comment: Are you running Bonita Studio and a Bonita Tomcat bundle on the same computer? Note that Bonita Studio embedded a Tomcat server to be able to simply test Bonita applications by running only Bonita Studio. Also can you mention which version of Bonita Studio are you using? Note that if Tomcat is already running on your computer before you start Bonita Studio, Bonita Studio embedded Tomcat should be able to reconfigure himself to use a different port then the default one (8080). An alternative might be to update your Tomcat bundle (if you use one) configuration to use different ports.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your Bonita Studio.

Cheers!!

Comment: I have written in my post above that restarting it doesn't work. I also wrote that restarting my laptop doesn't work either

Comment: try Bonita Studio Menu -> Server -> Restart engine or Restart web server

Comment: In my case, it worked in Bonita Studio 7.7.4
The port was 8080, now it is 52877.
It may depend on the Bonita studio version.

Comment: Yeah maybe they fix it in the later versions. Thanks for your time, I'll try to find another way.

Comment: Yesterday I was having multiple issues regarding Bonita studio including yours... then I tried this [link](https://bonita.atlassian.net/browse/BBPMC-530?focusedCommentId=31484&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-31484)

Comment: Thanks. I will try that later, and send you an update

Comment: Hi sorry just got time to try the one in the link you shared, but I still got the same problem. I tried running my portal, and already it wouldn't load and just went like it usually does.

Comment: I had the same problem as Grandevox using Bonita Studio Community 7.9.2 - I had changed port, restared the web server, Bonita Studio and whole system multiple times - without any effect. Then I changed port to 52877 (as @AsadShakeel suggested) and server suddenly started working after restarting. I'm still not sure if this specific port made the difference or restarting the web server so many times.