# Tomcat Geonetwork port already in use

Tags: java, tomcat, localhost, geonetwork

I am trying to install Geonetwork via Tomcat, but cannot access to it.

First of all, I installed Tomcat, but when running it, I was facing the following problem:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d9WD.png)

I went to the server.xml file to change the shutdown port from 8005 to 8006 and it did work, I can go to localhost:8080 succesfully.

After that, I pasted the geonetwork.war in the webapps folder, but the same error occurs.

I have access to localhost:8080 but i cant reach localhost:8080/geonetwork

apache-tomcat-10.1.13

Java SE Development Kit 20.0.2

ntoskrnl.exe is using port 8005

Any ideas?? thanks a lot!

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. If the port is already in use you need to stop the program that's using the port. On Linux, use `lsof -i | grep :8080` to find what is using port 8080. No idea if Windows has a similar command. Alternatively, change your server configuration to use a different port.

Comment: Maybe: this answer in stackoverflow helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147510/port-8005-is-used-by-windows-10-system-process