# executing shutdown.sh script as sudo-user not working

Tags: unix, tomcat, sudo, shutdown

I want to shut down a tomcat server. To this end I went to the bin directory of the tomcat installation and wanted to execute the shutdown.sh script, as described in the approved answer to this question:

[Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat Server at localhost are already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre)

I first simply tried

```
./shutdown.sh
```

I received the following error message:

```
-bash: ./shutdown.sh: Permission denied
```

So I tried the following command:

```
 sudo ./shutdown.sh
```

This gave me the following error message:

```
sudo: ./shutdown.sh: command not found
```

So how can I run the shutdown.sh script as sudo-user? What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run

```
sudo -i /path/to/executable.sh
```

Since the `-i` flag:

> [Run's] login shell as the target user

Answer (score 0):

Try granting privileges by

```
chmod 755 ./shutdown.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

run bellows,

```
sudo chmod 777 shutdown.sh
sudo ./shutdown.sh
```