# My Apache Tomcat is not running in eclipse ide

Tags: tomcat

I am using Eclipse IDE to Develop JavaScript application.I used same  ide to develop java application.so,when i try to change the port numbers it is showing the error

"Several ports (8015, 8085, 8019) required by Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)."

How to solve this error please explain with Pictures.Thank you

Comment: double click on the server, change the port numbers. say 8015->8016 and restart

Comment: If the servers window isn't visible, click on window->show view -> servers. Then double click on the tomcat server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat Server at localhost are already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre)

Comment: I did what you said but this error "Several ports (8085, 8019) required by Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)."

Comment: hi @Alan Pallath firstly i used 8005,8080,8009 for java development.Now i changed to 8016,8085,8019

Comment: you've changed only one. change 8085 to 8086 and 8019 to 8020. It will work

Comment: those ports may be used for any other purposes. so try changing to another port number.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of solving the issue. The quickest way is to change the port numbers. But, this is not the right method as apache will use both ports. For doing this, double click on the apache tomcat server in the **Servers** window which opens up the Server Properties. To the right side there will be a box **Ports** where the 3 ports will be there. Change the numbers(Increment by one) and restart the server.

This can be efficiently solved by manually stopping the server and then using the server in eclipse. More on that on this thread [Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat Server at localhost are already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Change the port of your server..

1. Double click on your server.
2. change the port to 8090.
3. Save it.
4. Run the server again.

Comment: Double click on your server??? can you elaborate this step.  Where is this in eclipse?