# First jee project not executing

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server

Configured Tomcat 9.0,  using eclipse oxygen for ide.

On first go, got error "httpServet"  cannot be resolved.
Looked up for an answer here which mentions to create a new server (instance) and set project to new server "project > properties > targeted runtime".
Did so, error disappears.

But on run, get error "ports 8080,8009,8005 required by server already in use".
Reconfigured ports in "server.xml" but the problems persists.
Suggestions plz !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved by changing eclipse version from oxygen to neon and no changes in any other environment.
It worked like a sharp hot knife through butter!

Oxygen is bugged. The older versions are sorted.
No changes in server version made yet it worked properly.. moral is ditch oxygen resort to neon. 
Old seems to be gold here !

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem.Use Tomcat 8.5.24. Or change eclipse J2EE to older versions like neon package. I think problem is solved.

or see the answer

[Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat Server at localhost are already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre)

or see the sort tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnmYA839_1M

and or

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWv-LPkBxng

It will be helpful.

Comment: what problem you face?? would you please tell briefly??

Comment: Ok thanks ,ill get this sorted ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your tomcat service is set to manual start not automatic, kill the service using task manager / services. If you can't find it try searching for the tomcat process > right click and go to service and then stop it.

Comment: @Mehadi Hassan dude u were right.. The older eclipse versions work seemlessly.. oxygen is trouble... I dint even have to resort to older tomcat versions becoz 9.0 worked fine on neon. Thanks. ...