# Can't start tomcatv9.0 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

[Server Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12lRw.png)I am getting an error while trying to start tomcat from eclipse. The error message shows.

```
The server cannot be started because one or more of the ports are invalid. Open the server editor and correct the invalid ports.
```

what I have done is installed tomcat v9.0 and eclipse oxygen and connected tomcat with eclipse.

```
Windows 7 - 32 bit
Eclipse Oxygen
Tomcat v9.0
```

Please help me!

The error message is...

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqvFN.png)

I followed an udemy course "Spring & Hibernate for Beginners"

Comment: Please show what port numbers you currently have.

Comment: i have configure tomcat for port number 8080 which is currently free. and i have stopped the windows services also.

Comment: i have configure tomcat for port number 8080 which is currently free. and i have stopped the windows services also. Tomcat admin port - -, HTTP/1.1 - 8080, AJP/1.3 - 8009

Comment: I have added the picture of the error message please refer it..

Comment: I am a beginner of these java things

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The admin port is set to '-' which is not correct. Set it e.g. to 8005 or some other free port.

Answer (score 6):

Helo, probably you not configured TomCat admin port yet. It's easy:

In Eclipse TomCat overview configuration, just assign a number to a TomCat admin port. The number can be 8085.

[image: TomCat Overview in Eclipse]

After that, if you get the error "Port 8080 required by Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost is already in use" signify that you has two Tomcat instances and both your installed and launched instance can not both listen on the same port at the same time. You'll have to change one of them or in windows you can stop the Tomcat running service in command line:

```
net stop Tomcat9
```