# Starting tomcat server at localhost has encountered a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Basically I have followed all the instructions to run Java EE programs. I have downloaded and installed *tomcat apache* server and configured 8080 port on it (it runs successfully on my pc). And I have downloaded and installed Eclipse IDE and connected it to the server.

Then I tried testing it via this simple code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Hello World</h3>
        <p>The time on server is <%= new java.util.Date()  %></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But whenever I run it I faced this problem:

> **Starting tomcat server at localhost has encountered a problem**

You can see the full error message in this image

[image]

Comment: do you have another instances of the server running???

Comment: or, as the error says, you could have other process using those ports that need to be stopped for tomcat to work

Comment: Stop the server which is using your current port and start the server.Follow these instructions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146401/error-with-port-8080-already-in-use

Comment: Hi, your port 8080 is busy. Do you have skype running ? Most of the time skype is the problem (it uses 8080 as alternative port). You have to change this setting or just quit skype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two ways to resolve the query:

1. Try to kill the process on port 8080 and re run the tomcat.
2. Run the tomcat on other port. Steps to change the port are as below:

http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-change-port-numbers-for-tomcat-in-eclipse

Comment: Great answer and now I have faced this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46238055/the-origin-server-did-not-find-a-current-representation-for-the-target-resource